# Responsive jquery is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a new responsive website, the html and css is done, but the JavaScript / Jquery not. The problem is that the responsive part of the jquery is not working correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width > 1023) {
   $('#wrapper').hide();
}
else {
   $('#wrapper').show();
   $('#footer').hide();
}
});
```

The problem is that in a way the jquery doesn't detect the width while JavaScript is enabled and Jquery and Jquery UI are included.

Comment: The `width` property of a jQuery object [is a function](http://api.jquery.com/width/) so you have to use it as such `.width()`

Comment: Why not using `@media-query` of css for responsive design? Describe how it's not working? When changing window size you see no effect, because there is no `$(window).resize()` event

Comment: @Justinas I know that, but when i resize the browser to 500px width, and I refresh the site still nothing happends. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `resize` event

*Example*

```
//Use resize event
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1023) { //Type width() is a function
       $('#wrapper').hide();
    }
    else {
       $('#wrapper').show();
       $('#footer').hide();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize();    //Trigger resize event on page load
});
```

Comment: It's exatly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`width` is not a property, it's a function that returns a number. You have to use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($(window).width() > 1023) {
       $('#wrapper').hide();
    }
    else {
       $('#wrapper').show();
       $('#footer').hide();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media-query than javacript it is very simple and useful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (window.innerWidth > 1023) {
    $('#wrapper').hide();
 } else {
    $('#wrapper').show();
    $('#footer').hide();
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Why is it better then the if ($(document).width? They both shoud work wright?